# How to work with an arbitrary set of source files in Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, build-system

I have a makefile that looks like this:

```
SRCS :=         $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJS :=         $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRCS))
TARGET :=       foo
default :       $(TARGET)
%.o : %.cpp %.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
$(TARGET) :     $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $(TARGET)
```

This assumes all the source files I need are at the same place.
What should I do if the files I want to build are (foo.cpp ../bar.cpp ../../xip/bas.cpp ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need `VPATH`, [4.5.1 VPATH: Search Path for All Prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html),
plus `$(notdir ...)`[8.3 Functions for File Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html)

If your source files were as you suggest `foo.cpp`, `../bar.cpp`, `../../xip/bas.cpp )`
then your makefile would look like:

```
VPATH := ..:../../xip/
SRCS :=         $(notdir foo.cpp ../bar.cpp ../../xip/bas.cpp)
OBJS :=         $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRCS))
TARGET :=       foo
default :       $(TARGET)
%.o : %.cpp %.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
$(TARGET) :     $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $(TARGET)
```